# Parsing and editing source code using bash-script

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

I do have several source code files (.cpp) containing the following line:

```
other stuff
...
TRACE(arg1, arg2, ...);
...
other stuff
```

where arg1, arg2, ... denote arbitrary function call arguments separated by a comma and possibly preceded by a whitespace.

The goal is to parse each line in each source file in my project and remove the first argument (arg1) from the function call TRACE, such as

```
TRACE(arg2, arg3, ...);
```

Note that function TRACE can be preceded by an arbitrary number of whitespace and can itself contain the string TRACE such as

```
TRACE(0, TRACE_INFO, "Test ");
    TRACE(  0 , TRACE, 4,5 ,6);
```

Is there an easy way to do so ?

A test file test.cpp contains:

```
   TRACE( "I2Ccontrol::I2Ccontrol", TRACE_FATAL,0);
```

3 White spaces, no preceding lines no following lines

Answer (score 3):

Using sed with extended regex:

```
sed -r 's/(\bTRACE\()([^",]+,\s*|\s*"[^"]*"\s*,\s*)(.*\);)/\1\3/' file
```

To change the file in-place use `sed --in-place -r ...`

EDIT:

Testing input from comment:

```
echo '   TRACE( "I2Ccontrol::I2Ccontrol", TRACE_FATAL,0);' |sed -r 's/(\bTRACE\()([^",]+,\s*|\s*"[^"]*"\s*,\s*)(.*\);)/\1\3/'
#three white space before TRACE
```

Output:

```
   TRACE(TRACE_FATAL,0);
```

Comment: Great. This solution supports even commas in the value of `arg1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! will this also work (in place) for multiple files like:
sed --in-place -r ... file1 file2 ... ?

Comment: But wont there be a whitespace left over after each bracket now ?
Such as TRACE( arg2,...

Comment: True just consistency in coding style.
I have one Issue left though:
A function call could look like this:
TRACE(0, TRACE_INFO, "Test ", ...
This would not only remove the 0 but also arg2 in this case TRACE_INFO
which is certainly a real issue

Comment: Doesn't work.
Content of test.cpp:
   TRACE( "I2Ccontrol::I2Ccontrol", TRACE_FATAL,0); (preceeded with 3 whitespaces)

The following command
sed --in-place -r 's/(\bTRACE\()([^",]+,\s*|\s*"[^"]*",\s*)(.*\);)/\1\3/' test.cpp

doesnt affect the file test.cpp at all

Comment: @FloRyan It gives `TRACE(TRACE_FATAL,0);` here...Number of whitespace before `TRACE(` doesn't matter, those white spaces are left intact.

Comment: @Jahid
sed --in-place -r 's/(\bTRACE()([^",]+,\s*|\s*"[^"]*",\s*)(.*);)/\1\3/' test.cpp
really doesn't work on my file. I'm hopeless. I cant provide a screenshot as my reputation for posting pics is too low.

Comment: @FloRyan That's strange, do you really have the `-r` flag available with sed ?

Comment: @FloRyan I have posted a test command, copy paste that command in terminal (as it is, no chnage) and see the output...

Comment: @Jahid I'm getting your output. It seems it just does'nt work on the content of a file.

Comment: @FloRyan That means it works, right? may be there are other issues here... may be the test.cpp is changed already and doesn't have that string at all now....

Comment: @Jahid As mentionned the file contains one line. The content doesn't change after calling  sed --in-place -r 's/(\bTRACE()([^",]+,\s*|\s*"[^"]*",\s*)(.*);)/\1\3/' test.cpp

Comment: @FloRyan Can you post the exact line (with one before and after) from test.cpp? (not in comment, editing your post)

Comment: @FloRyan No matter how many times I try it works every time. Do your file have Unix line ending or dos line ending? are you running in cygwin?

Comment: @Jahid I have now tried it on two different machines, one running Xubuntu 14.04 and one running ubuntu 14.04. I have created the files using gedit so I am pretty sure its UNIX file ending. Without --in-place there is still no change

Comment: @FloRyan I am in Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (an I am using gedit too), and to be clear, without inplace there won't be any change in the file, it will only show output on terminal.

Comment: @Jahid That is clear to me. I'll go for python now. Thanks anyway

Comment: @FloRyan I have found a flaw, If you had space after arg1 i.e between `arg1` and `,` it wouldn't match. If that's the reason then the current regex will work..